# WordPress cannot call pagination method on a custom page template [i-Max theme]

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using i-Max theme.
I have a method call "imax_paging_nav" in the function.php file.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'imax_paging_nav' ) ) :

function imax_paging_nav() {

global $wp_query;

// Don't print empty markup if there's only one page.
if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 )
    return;
?>
<?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $args = array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'list',
        'prev_text' => '<span class="text">&laquo; ' . __( 'Previous', 'i-max' ) . '</span>',
        'next_text' => '<span class="text">' . __( 'Next', 'i-max' ) . ' &raquo;</span>',
        'add_args' => false                 
    );
?>                  
<nav class="navigation paging-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Posts navigation', 'i-max' ); ?></h1>
    <div class="nav-links">
        <div id="posts-nav" class="navigation">
            <?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
        </div><!-- #posts-nav -->
    </div><!-- .nav-links -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
<?php
}
endif;
```

I saw this method called on index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  ?>
        <div class="blog-columns" id="blog-cols">
        <?php /* The loop normal posts */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php imax_paging_nav(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

then I have the page pagination like this
[image]

BUT when I create a new page template "page-news.php" and the pagination method doesn't work.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: News
*
*/

get_header(); ?>


<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php $allPosts = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish')); ?>
    <?php if ( $allPosts->have_posts() ) :  ?>
        <?php /* The loop normal posts */ ?>
        <?php while ( $allPosts->have_posts() ) : $allPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php imax_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

[image]

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution  here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops

I changed my custom page template as bellow then it works correctly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: News
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>


<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php 
        $customArgs = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish');
        $customArgs['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $allPosts = new WP_Query($customArgs);
        // Pagination fix
        $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query   = NULL;
        $wp_query   = $allPosts;            
    ?>
    <?php if ( $allPosts->have_posts() ) :  ?>
        <?php /* The loop normal posts */ ?>
        <?php while ( $allPosts->have_posts() ) : $allPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php imax_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; 
    // Reset postdata
    wp_reset_postdata();
    // Reset main query object
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #primary -->
```